# Use just some part of sensor kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I developed an application to use hands to move mouse cursor. But in the limits of computer screen, the cursor stay slow and run for other locations. I think that it is happens because I use all sensor of kinect. How I can use just part of sensor?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kinect you use, but the kinect one cannt dissable certain streams.
Its goes all over USB3 to your PC, and its up to your code if you subscribe to those streams or not, but it is delivered anyway.

i'm not realy sure for the older kinect, but i assume its the same.

i have noticed that speed can depend a lot on the hardware, how your usb3 behaves.
i have a beast of a laptop i7 though a small industrial i5 outperforms it when running my kinect programs.

- what you can do trough is drop frames, till your calculation is ready. that would keep most apps smooth working, if you dont want that try to create faster code you need roughly about 20ms to finish what you want to do till the next frame arives.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you have this block of code where you can modify your application to your needs.

```
//Creates a new frame reader for correlating multiple frame sources.
_reader = _sensor.OpenMultiSourceFrameReader(FrameSourceTypes.Color | FrameSourceTypes.Depth | FrameSourceTypes.Infrared | FrameSourceTypes.Body);
```